# How to know if a '97 Ford Escort Engine is Federal Emissions or California Emissions

Tags: engine, ford, emissions, escort

I did a search on the VIN and the engine type is listed as: 2.0L I4 SPI

Can anyone tell if it is California or Federal Emissions? From what I've been told they have completely different intake systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to tell. Your local ford dealer can tell by decoding the VIN (the vehicle indentification number). It is usually located on the dashboard at the base of the windshield on the drivers side. If you look under the hood there is usually a sticker on the frame near the radiator that will say complies with California or 49 state emissions. The sticker may be missing so a call to the Ford dealer is the most reliable.

Comment: Regarding the sticker, [this page](http://dmv.ca.gov/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffvr29.htm) from the California DMV shows what to look for.